# Prevent Pick from Drop-down List Option in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a form that to be used by my company's employees. One employee noticed that when right clicking on a cell, there is a "Pick From Drop-down List..." option in the menu. When using that option it will sometimes show some seemingly random options from elsewhere on the spreadsheet.

How can I prevent that option from appearing in the right click menu? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make that given option not visible with:

```
With Application.CommandBars("Cell")
        .Controls("Pick from drop-down list...").Visible = False
End With
```

Comment: Sorry I am not well versed in VBA, and I just started using it to do things like this. If I want this to work for the entire workbook, and be effective for all of the sheets, would I simply paste this code into the "ThisWorkbook" or sheet under Microsoft Excel Objects?

Comment: @TheDuckhat Paste it into your [`Worksheet_BeforeRightClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192993.aspx)  event.

Comment: @TheDuckhat Desired behavior?

Comment: I was able to use the following in the "ThisWorkbook" section:

Comment: Private Sub Workbook_BeforeRightClick()
    With Application.CommandBars("Cell")
            .Controls("Pick from drop-down list...").Visible = False
    End With
    End Sub

Comment: It did! I was able to work part of it into another piece of code I had in there so it is active when the workbook opens and goes away once it is closed. I would paste it in here, but I am having trouble how to get it formatted like your code up above.